# How to repopulate select2 field on edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

this select2 field isn't repopulating with the data when I'm using the same partial and form for editing the instance.  I've been researching it for a while without coming up with a solution.

It's my first website.

form

```
<%= f.input :song_creditor_1, label: 'Song Creditor 1', as: :select, input_html:  { id: "song_creditor_1", include_hidden: false } %>
```

script

```
<script> 
  function templateDropDownFormat (item) {
    return item.text;
  }

  function templateSelectionFormat (item) {
    return item.text;
  }

  $("#song_creditor_1").select2({ 
    placeholder: "Search",
    ajax: {
      url: "/songs",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },

      processResults: function (data, params) { 
        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
        // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
        // scrolling can be used
        params.page = params.page || 1;
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function(cnut) { 
              return { 
                text: cnut.name + ", " + cnut.city + ", " + cnut.country + " (" + cnut.account_type + ")",
                id: cnut.id, 
              }; 
          }),
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          }
        }; 
      }, 
      cache: true
    }, 
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: templateDropDownFormat, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    templateSelection: templateSelectionFormat// omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
  });
```

Comment: I think you just need to add the 'selected' attribute in your options.

Comment: Hi, if you could go into more detail I would appreciate it.

Comment: ... looks like https://jsfiddle.net/57co6c95/ is the solution, but I'm going to have to figure it out in detail, as it's slightly above me, unless you can quickly write an applicable answer :)